# Selecionar e arrastar componente Swing

Tags: java, swing

Fiz um aplicativo que desenha retângulos, pontos, retas, etc. Eu queria que quando o usuário clicasse com o mouse em cima de um polígono desenhado, selecionasse o polígono e arrastasse para onde ele quiser na tela, Como alcançar esse objetivo?

Comment: Eu não conheço muita coisa sobre o Swing, e já faz um tempo que não trabalho com Java. Mas acredito que nem o Swing nem o JavaFX têm esse tipo de funcionalidade, você teria que procurar uma biblioteca existente pra isso ou um manipulador (e fazer isso na mão daria um bom trabalho).

Comment: Eu queria fazer na mão mesmo, para me treinar mais no uso da linguagem, Mas se eu não conseguir, vou seguir sua dica :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você quer fazer na mão... já faz um tempo que não trabalho com Java, mas vou tentar dar umas dicas.

Sempre que o usuário desenhar um polígono, mantenha na memória as coordenadas desse polígono. É bom manter também uma espécie de "Z-index" pra poder ter polígonos um sobre o outro (caso você queira permitir isso)

```
private Vector<Poligono> poligonos;
public Vector<Poligono> getPoligonos() { return this.poligonos; }
public void setPoligonos(Vector<Poligono> poligonos) { this.poligonos = poligonos; }

public void desenharPoligono(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
    this.getPoligonos().push(new Poligono(startX, startY, endX, endY));
}
```

Quando o usuário fizer um clique rápido (não clicar e arrastar), faça uma varredura na sua lista de polígonos pra ver se ele clicou numa coordenada que pertence a um polígono... Se sim, bang, selecione seu polígono!

```
public void verificarCoordenadas(int x, int y) {
    for (Poligono poligono : this.getPoligonos()) {
        if (poligono.contemCoordenada(x, y)) {
            poligono.selecionar();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Se eu der mais dicas eu tiro o seu desafio de aprender sozinho. Seus próximos passos seriam criar a classe `Poligono` e implementar seus métodos (`contemCoordenada`, `selecionar`, `mover`  afins)...

Me deu um pouco de saudades de Java agora.

Comment: hum muito bom, já é um ótimo começo para me, valeu pela dica :D

Answer (score 1):

Não sei exatamente como você está criando os polígonos.

Mas se for um java.awt.Component creio que isso resolva:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Mover extends MouseAdapter {

  private Dimension snapSize = new Dimension( 1, 1 );
  private Component source;
  private Point pressed;
  private boolean potentialDrag;
  private static Mover instance;
  private Point locationBeforeMove;

  private Mover() {
  }

  public void deregisterComponent( Component... components ) {
    for ( Component component : components ) {
      component.removeMouseListener( this );
    }
  }

  public void registerComponent( Component... components ) {
    for ( Component component : components ) {
      component.addMouseListener( this );
    }
  }

  public Dimension getSnapSize() {
    return snapSize;
  }

  public void setSnapSize( Dimension snapSize ) {
    if ( snapSize.width < 1
        || snapSize.height < 1 ) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException( "snapSize deve ser maior que 0" );
    }

    this.snapSize = snapSize;
  }

  @Override
  public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e ) {
    if ( !SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton( e ) ) {
      return;
    }
    if ( e.isConsumed() ) {
      return;
    }

    setupForDragging( e );
  }

  private void setupForDragging( MouseEvent e ) {
    source = e.getComponent();
    source.addMouseMotionListener( this );
    potentialDrag = true;

    pressed = e.getLocationOnScreen();

    locationBeforeMove = source.getLocation();
  }

  /**
   * Move the component to its new location. The dragged Point must be in the destination coordinates.
   */
  @Override
  public void mouseDragged( MouseEvent e ) {
    if ( !SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton( e ) ) {
      return;
    }
    if ( e.isConsumed() ) {
      return;
    }
    Point dragged = e.getLocationOnScreen();
    int dragX = getDragDistance( dragged.x, pressed.x, snapSize.width );
    int dragY = getDragDistance( dragged.y, pressed.y, snapSize.height );

    Component source = e.getComponent();

    Point location = locationBeforeMove;
    if ( location == null ) {
      return;
    }

    int locationX = location.x + dragX;
    int locationY = location.y + dragY;

    while ( locationX < 0 ) {
      locationX += snapSize.width;
    }

    while ( locationY < 0 ) {
      locationY += snapSize.height;
    }

    Dimension d = getBoundingSize( source );

    while ( locationX + source.getSize().width > d.width ) {
      locationX -= snapSize.width;
    }

    while ( locationY + source.getSize().height > d.height ) {
      locationY -= snapSize.height;
    }

    source.setLocation( locationX, locationY );
  }


  private int getDragDistance( int larger, int smaller, int snapSize ) {
    int halfway = snapSize / 2;
    int drag = larger - smaller;
    drag += (drag < 0) ? -halfway : halfway;
    drag = (drag / snapSize) * snapSize;

    return drag;
  }

  private Dimension getBoundingSize( Component source ) {
    if ( source instanceof Window ) {
      GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
      Rectangle bounds = env.getMaximumWindowBounds();
      return new Dimension( bounds.width, bounds.height );
    }
    else {
      return source.getParent().getSize();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseReleased( MouseEvent e ) {
    if ( !SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton( e ) ) {
      return;
    }
    if ( !potentialDrag ) {
      return;
    }

    source.removeMouseMotionListener( this );
    potentialDrag = false;
  }

  public static Mover getInstance() {
    if ( instance == null ) {
      instance = new Mover();
    }
    return instance;
  }
}
```

Para utilizar a classe:

```
Poligono poligono = new Poligono();
Mover.getInstance().registerComponent( poligono );
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente acho que tem que rever o uso do Swing pois e não vai ser continuada, sugiro o uso do Java FX que e muito bacana, fácil de usar e tem componentes bem legais.

Sobre o problema você teria que utilizar algum recurso de *drag & drop*, que irá trabalhar com as posições da imagem. Algo nesse gênero.

Comment: Vou dar uma pesquisa em como funciona o java FX, valeu pela dica!

Answer (score 0):

Dependendo do objetivo disso, teria que fazer "no braço": Detectando aonde o cara clicou, identificando qual o polígono é, e repintar o polígono na tela movendo ele e por aí vai... Isso depende de como vc ta desenhando o polígono

Comment: Estou desenhando com as primitivas da API gráfica do java, a dificuldade é identifica se o cara clicou em cima do polígono, tem como me da uma dica de como fazer isso...

Comment: na faculdade eu tive que fazer um problema como esse e a solução encontrada foi identificar qual o ponto mais perto do local clicado. A partir disso via de qual polígono pertencia aquele ponto e selecionava.

Comment: hum, vou tentar utilizar essa ideia aqui :D